# Why we need $\phi(t)$ to be continuously differentiable function in Substitution Rule.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

If $f$ is a continuous function defined on $[a, b],$ and $\phi(t)$ a continuously differentiable function from $[\alpha, \beta]$ into $[a, b]$. Then

$\int_\alpha^\beta{f(\phi(t)) \phi\prime (t)dt}=\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$

[image]

This is proof.Question I have is that why we need  $\phi(t)$ to be continuously differentiable function?Why we need that derivative of $\phi(t)$ to be continuous?I can't see where we used that.

Comment: Continuity is the simplest way to make sure the integral exists.  This could be relaxed a little bit.

Comment: @Randall If function is not continuous at finitely many points it still can be integrable.But inside integral we have $f((ϕ(t))ϕ′(t)$ not only $\phi(t)$

Comment: Meaning that even if your statement is correct inside integral is  $f((ϕ(t))ϕ'(t)$ why if $\phi'(t)$ is continuous follows that integral exists?

Comment: Because you're integrating a product of continuous functions, which is continuous.

Comment: But if $f=0$ we can have that $ϕ′(t) $ to be discontinuous or not?

Comment: I don't understand what $f$ has to do with $\phi'(t)$.

Comment: There's no claim that the condition is strictly necessary. You could for instance split the integral wherever $\phi'$ is discontinuous and then apply this result on each piece, and then you'd get a slight generalization.

Comment: All that said, it is rarely necessary to pay much attention to functions which are differentiable but not continuously differentiable. They don't come up much in practice (partially because a function that is the derivative of something can only have a "type II" discontinuity, which aren't that common in practice either). So I would suggest not dwelling on the "continuously" part of "continuously differentiable" hypotheses in theorems.

Comment: @Randall Inside integral it is $f(\phi(t))ϕ′(t) $ product of two functions.You are saying that we need  $ϕ′(t)$ to be continuous so that product of two functions to be also continuous.But if $f=0$ then  $f(\phi(t))ϕ′(t)=0$ which means that $ϕ′(t)$  can be discontinuous?

Comment: @unit1991 OK, sure, but then you're integrating the $0$ function, and we don't need any fancy theorems at all to do that.

Comment: @Ian is saying it best.  No one is stating that the condition is necessary.

Comment: @unit1991.  If $f$ is continuous, then it is sufficient only that $\phi'$ be Riemann integrable for the rule to hold.  On the other hand, if we weaken the condition on $f$ -- for example assume only that $f$ is Riemann integrable -- then in some proofs, it is necessary to assume that $\phi'$ is continuous.  See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3747622/148510). In your case what really matters is that $f \circ \phi \phi'$ is integrable.

Comment: @RRL Thank you.I will think more about that and read your linked question.

Comment: @Ian $ϕ′(t)$  can be discontinuous only in finitely many points yes?So only that way we can apply on each piece.

Comment: @unit1991: Also see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4117822/148510) -- particularly the comments.

Comment: @RRL in here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3746099/understanding-the-substitution-theorem-of-riemann-integration/3747622#3747622 how you got $F'(t) = f(\phi(t)) \phi'(t)$?

Comment: @unit1991: Leibniz rule. In future you should ask a question about another answer by commenting there.

Comment: @unit1991 Doing this splitting without getting into further technicalities requires only finitely many discontinuities yes.

Comment: Apply chain rule to differentiate $F(t) = G(\phi(t))$ where $G(x) = \int_{\phi(a)}^x f(u)\, du$.  SInce $f$ is continuous $G'(x) = f(x)$ and by the chain rule $F'(t) = G'(\phi(t))\phi'(t)$.

Comment: @RRL Now I understand thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This question has generated quite a few comments.   In view of this interest you might want to know a more definitive answer.  Preiss and Uher published this in their days as students in Prague.

**Preiss, David; Uher, Jaromír
A remark on the substitution for the Riemann integral. (Czech. English summary)
Časopis Pěst. Mat. 95 1970 345–347.**

> *Theorem*: Let $g $  be a Riemann integrable function on $[a,b]$; for $s∈[a,b]$ put $G(t)=∫_s^t g(w)dw$  $(t∈[a,b])$; let $f$ be a function
> bounded on $[c,d]=G([a,b])$; then if either one of the Riemann
> integrals $∫_a^b f(G(t))g(t)dt$, $∫_{G(a)}^{G(b)}f(x)dx$ exists, the
> other exists also and these integrals are equal.

The proof is based on an earlier result of R. O. Davies [Math. Gaz. 45 (1961), 23–25].

An online proof for this (in English, not Czech) can be found here:
http://www.teaching.math.rs/vol/tm1813.pdf